# Java - print user input of 4 integers, and the lowest, highest and average number

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

This program is supposed to take user input of four grades, take these grades and calculate the lowest, highest and average of them. Then it needs to print out the four grades along with the lowest, highest, and average of them with proper labels. I cannot figure out how to print out the four grades with my code, and for some reason it prints out the lowest, highest and average after every iteration of the loop, or every user input.

Here is what I have so far:

public class Test2 {

```
double total = 0.0;
double max = 0.0;
double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;

public void Test2 (double[] grades){
//Loop through all of the grades.
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){

    double grade = grades[i];
    //Add the grade to the total
    total += grade;

    //If this is the highest grade we've encountered, set as the max.
    if(max < grade){
        max = grade;
    }
    //If this is the lowest grade we've encountered, set as min.
    if(min > grade){
        min = grade;
    }
}
    System.out.println("Average is: " + (total / 4));
    System.out.println("Max is: " + max);
    System.out.println("Min is: " + min); }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double[] grades = new double[4];

    System.out.println("Please enter number");

    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        grades[i] = input.nextDouble();
        Test2 g = new Test2();
        g.Test2(grades);
    } } }
```

Can anyone help me with this? I need it to print out the four grades (user input), along withe the lowest, highest and average grade from the four grades, but ONLY ONCE, not after every iteration of the loop. Sorry if my code looks bad.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: M.itani answer worked perfectly thank you.

Comment: If that's the case, then you should show your appreciation by upvoting and accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call the method `Test2(double grade)` only once in the main method as there is a for loop inside `Test2` method. I.e call `Test2` method in main outside for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer should be the below class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test2 {

double total = 0.0;
double max = 0.0;
double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;

public void doOperations(double[] grades) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        double grade = grades[i];
        //Add the grade to the total
        total += grade;

        //If this is the highest grade we've encountered, set as the max.
        if (max < grade) {
            max = grade;
        }
        //If this is the lowest grade we've encountered, set as min.
        if (min > grade) {
            min = grade;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Average is: " + (total / 4));
    System.out.println("Max is: " + max);
    System.out.println("Min is: " + min);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double[] grades = new double[4];

        System.out.println("Please enter number");

        for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
            grades[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }
        Test2 test2 = new Test2();
        test2.doOperations(grades);


}
```

}